# Invalid Authenticity Token When Multiple Tabs Open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, csrf

I have a Rails 4.2 application. Several months ago we started experiencing Invalid Authenticity Token errors. I've discovered that the following scenario reproduces the error:

1) User opens up browser and visit's ourwebsite.com/log-in.

2) User opens up second tab in the same browser and visits ourwebsite.com/enroll-in-course.

3) User goes back to tab one and logs in submitting a POST form.

4) User goes to tab two and submits a POST form on the enroll-in-course page.

5) Error appears.

---

Here's some general information about our app:

- We are using Devise 3.4.1 with zero customization applied.
- Our application controller runs `protect_from_forgery with: :exception`.
- We use Turbolinks 2.5.
- We are not caching either forms.
- We run `Turbolinks.pagesCached(0);` in our Javascript on all pages.
- To reiterate, both forms in the above scenario are POST forms. They work perfectly fine except in the above scenario.
- From my knowledge, we have not made any changes in handling user sessions or CSRF tokens.

I have a theory that because we log in the user, the csrf_token stored in the session changes. Thus when the user submits a form in the second tab, the token from form will not match the token in the session and an InvalidAuthenticityToken is raised. What's wrong and how do I fix this? Better yet, is this even fixable?

Comment: What were the results/resolution/culprit in this case?